# launching steam and discord at startup

Tags: steam

OK so I've been launching steam and discord manually every time i turn on my computer, i'm tired of it. I've tried using the startup application but i have to use terminal commands and if i launch through terminal the terminal window must be open otherwise if i try to close it the application closes in both cases with discord or steam. how can i avoid using the terminal command in the startup application, close the terminal without closing the app, avoid using startup application, or have i simply missed a check box somewhere?

i;m using Ubuntu 22.04 using the commands: `steam` and `discord`
it's very possible i;m missing information about how to use the startup app

Comment: Edit your question and add the following information. The OS and version, and the exact commands you typed in the Startup Application for both steam and discord. The startup application is perfectly capable of launching a GUI app without opening a terminal. Something is wrong.

Comment: I've updated with the information asked, my apologies for missing that

Comment: user68186 i was completely unaware there was a folder containing all of these .desktop files being in this folder. i did find steam and have set it up to launch now as i did figure out how to select a file in start up (it's been years since i touched the application so i completely forgot how to use it) discord was not there but in all honesty i'm not as concerned about that as i don't always use it anyway. thanks a lot for the help, i was completely lost without you lol

Comment: I will convert my comments to an answer, so that you can accept it by clicking on the gray check mark next to the answer and turn it green. This will mark your problem solved and help others.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to do this is to use the **Startup Applications**. Since you are having problems with that application, I will show you another way.

## Copy files from the system folder to your personal folder

Look inside the two files called something like `steam.desktop` and `discord.desktop` in the folder `/usr/share/applications/`. Copy these files into the folder `/homre/$USER/.config/autostart/`.

You may have to use `sudo` to copy these files. If you need to use `sudo` then you will want to change the ownership of the copied files (not the original files). Use the command:

```
sudo <your-username> ~/.config/autostart/<name-of-the-file.desktop>
```

Replace the parts inside <..> with the actual information. Do not include the `<` and the `>` in the commands.

Now if you open the Startup applications again you will see these entries.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The Startup Applications shouldn't open a terminal window on login though...
I'll give different examples for **Startup Applications** first
Open Startup Applications and add a new entry.
Then write the following in the command section:

Discord Flatpak (minimized):
`bash -c "sleep 6 && flatpak run com.discordapp.Discord --start-minimized"`
This way it waits for 6 seconds after you login and then it opens discord minimized.

Discord Flatpak (Minimized Without Timer):
`flatpak run com.discordapp.Discord --start-minimized`

Discord (Minimized Non Flatpak):
`discord --start-minimized`

Steam (Minimized Non Flatpak):
`steam -nochatui -nofriendsui -silent`

Steam Flatpak:
`flatpak run com.valvesoftware.Steam -silent`
OR
 `flatpak run com.valvesoftware.Steam -nochatui -nofriendsui -silent`
*I don't use steam as flatpak, I'm not sure if this last one works*

**If Startup Applications really doesn't work for you, try the following:**
Copy `steam.desktop` and `discord.desktop` inside `/usr/share/applications/` to `/home/$USER/.config/autostart/`.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop /home/$USER/.config/autostart/
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/discord.desktop /home/$USER/.config/autostart/
```

Just in case change the ownership of the new .desktop files you copied:

```
sudo chown $USER /home/$USER/.config/autostart/steam.desktop
sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.config/autostart/steam.desktop
```

OR

```
sudo chown 1000 /home/$USER/.config/autostart/steam.desktop
sudo chown 1000:1000 /home/$USER/.config/autostart/steam.desktop
```

Repeat the steps above for discord.

If you want it to start minimized, edit with your text editor of choice the `steam.desktop` in `/home/$USER/.config/autostart/`
Find the `Exec=` line and do this:`Exec=/usr/games/steam -nochatui -nofriendsui -silent`